# Debugging multiple projects in a single solution

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, msbuild, postsharp

Is there any way around the issue of a debugger being raised for each project in a solution when debugging with PostSharp? Currently I have 14 projects in my solution and trying to debug just one of them with PostSharp seems to be very difficult because a debugger attach window pops up for each project in the solution.  If I choose to attach to the wrong debugger process the breakpoint I have set does not get hit and then, when it starts building the next project it pops up another window which does not have my active VS instance in it.  Is there a flag on msbuild I can use to say "use the same debugger process for all requirements of a debugger process" or something to that effect?

Comment: How are the assemblies produced by the projects hosted at runtime? In one single process, or one process per assembly, or something else? What is the host process?

Comment: The assemblies are compiled by VS 2013 in one process afaik, hope this answers your question because I'm not too sure I understood it.

Comment: A debugger attaches to a process, not a project or solution. So if you only have one process at debug/runtime, then the attach window should only appear once. But I don't know what effect PostSharp may be having, never having used it. Try running your application outside the debugger, and use Debug, Attach to Process in VS to attach to your application's process.

Comment: The application is not running when I start the debugger.  I call msbuild (as shown in the documentation from PostSharp) and then the attach windows pop up.  When I select my project in the VS instance list, that is when it attaches, but then that same VS instance cannot be attached to any other processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you're debugging the compile-time logic of your aspect following the steps from the [PostSharp documentation](http://doc.postsharp.net/debugging).

When you set the "attach debugger" property on the command-line, as shown below, the property will be set for all the projects involved in the build. And so the attaching to the debugger is invoked for each of those projects.

```
msbuild MyAspects.Test.csproj /T:Rebuild /P:PostSharpAttachDebugger=True
```

What you can do instead, is to set the property only for one project where you need it, by temporarily editing the *.csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PostSharpAttachDebugger>True</PostSharpAttachDebugger>
    <!-- ... -->
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If you don't want to edit the *.csproj directly, then you can put *PostSharp.Custom.targets* file in the project's directory, and define the property in that file.

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostSharpAttachDebugger>True</PostSharpAttachDebugger>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```